# how to create a function iterator xs f where xs is a list and f is one-seated function in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to write a function `iterator` that I can use as
`iterator l f` , where `l` is a list of `Int` numbers and `f` is a one-argument function. The `iterator` function should check that when the `f` function is applied to first element of the list it == the second element of the list and so on for all of the elements. It should return true if every element is equal to the previous one once `f` is is applied it .

It should work like this:

```
iterator [3,4,5] (+1) -> True
iterator [2,4,5] (+1) -> False
```

I was trying to write a function that takes the list and the f function and checks if its true for the head of the list and the second one, and then in the iterator function to `map` that function applied to the list, but it's not compiling and I don't know if my idea is right.

Here is my most recent attempt:

```
func xs f1 
      | null xs = False
      | ((head xs) f1)==(head(tail xs))=True
      | otherwise = False  
iterator l f 
      | null l = False
      | map (func l f) l ==True=True
      | otherwise = False
```

Comment: Some comments that may help to make your question clearer: 1) It is `iterator` that is a function, not `iterator l f`. 2) What does "one-seated" mean?

Comment: Have you seen a little function called `zipWith`?  You could implement this as `iterator xs f = and $ zipWith (==) (map f xs) $ tail xs`

Comment: `map (func l f) l == True` makes no sense. The result of `map` is a list, while `True` is a `Bool`, so it makes no sense to compare these values for equality. GHC is surely complaining about this as well, try using these error messages to fix your code.

Comment: one-seated mean the f should be either (+1) or (-1) function

Comment: I think `iterator [] _` should be `True`. That fits with mathematical logic, but also with the recursive definition (you should understand and use bheklilr's excellent definition, not this one): `iterator (x:y:ys) f = f x == y && iterator (y:ys) f` which means the base case is `iterator _ _ = True`. Seeing as `iterator [a] _` should be True, but trivially, so should `iterator [] _`.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you meant?

```
iterator :: (Eq a) => [a] -> (a -> a) -> Bool
iterator xs f = and . zipWith (==) xs . iterate f . head $ xs
```

this follows your intuition: the list *is* the result of *iterating* the supplied function, starting with the list's head element.

We could write `iterator xs f = xs == take (length xs) (iterate f $ head xs)` but using `length` would make it less *online*. And if we'd inline the definitions of `==`, `take`, `length` and fuse them, the result would be our `zipWith` code.

testing:

> Prelude> iterator [3,4,5] (+1) 
>       True 
>       Prelude> iterator [2,4,5] (+1) 
>       False

Answer (score 4):

What you really want to be doing is comparison like

```
-- with the list [x1, x2, x3, x4] and function f

    [f x1, f x2, f x3]
==  [  x2,   x3,   x4]
```

So there's `N-1` comparisons occurring for a list of length `N`.  This problem is pretty easily solved using functions in `Prelude`.  If you realize that `[x2, x3, x4] == tail xs`, and `[f x1, f x2, f x3] == map f (init xs)`.  Since we're comparing each element, we can do a `zipWith (==)` on these two lists, or we can just use list's `Eq` instance.  However, I'll prefer to use `zipWith` since it lets us remove the call to `init`, since `zipWith` will stop when either list runs out of elements.  The last step is to `and` the results together and the solution is complete:

```
iterator :: Eq a => [a] -> (a -> a) -> Bool
iterator xs f = and $ zipWith (==) (map f xs) (tail xs)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
iterator :: (Eq a) => [a] -> (a -> a) -> Bool
iterator [] _ = error "undefined operation on empty list"
iterator xs f = fst $ foldl foo (True, head xs) (tail xs)
  where foo (False, _) b = (False, b)
      foo (True, a) b  = (b == f a, b)
```

Comment: this won't work for e.g. `iterator ([1..5]++[10..]) (1+)`. though `iterator ([1..5]++[10, error "e"]) (1+)` works OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
coherent :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
coherent p (x : xs@(x2 : _)) | x `p` x2  = coherent p xs
                             | otherwise = False
coherent _ _                             = True
```

then

```
continuous :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> [a] -> Bool
continuous succ  =  coherent (\ x x2 -> succ x == x2)
```